# Optimized web data grids - ASP .NET vs ASP .NET MVC and jQuery

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, datagrid

I am developing a web application that will display data in grid form. I need to be able to load thousands of rows quickly. I also need to be able to sort data by multiple columns and filter columns by search string.  I am currently using ASP .NET MVC and [Infragistics jQuery iGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/jquery-controls/grid.aspx#Overview).

At the moment I am loading 1000 records and have already started to hit some performance problems.

I was originally using pagination to make the inital load quicker, however this means I need to do my sorting/filtering server side otherwise it will only sort/filter the records on that page, and not on the entire datasource.

Alternatively I can load the entire datasource into the grid (which with 1000 records takes ~20 secs to bind) and then do all sorting/filtering client side which is pretty much instantaneous.

My colleague reckons we should scrap the jQuery controls and use the [ASP .NET controls](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet.aspx#Overview) instead.  They are more mature and have more functionality.

Is it worth taking my colleague's advice?  Will the ASP .NET controls be faster than the jQuery controls?  Should I move to a straight ASP .NET project or would it be worth trying to incorporate the ASP .NET controls into an MVC project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It depends of your jQuery grid control (if it's using JSON for paging, I think there is no performance problems).
I use two differents grids on two apps :
- Telerik RadGrid with ASP.NET, mature, with lots of options and, with a good server side code, with good performance
- My own jquery grid implementation with JSON and ASP.NET MVC on server side. Less more options but a better performance.
You cannot have good perfs without pagination, that's the point.

The jQuery UI team will provide a new grid component in a few weeks I think. So it may be cool for you.

Comment: Both grids provide pagination and are easily implemented.  And yes the jQuery grid control uses JSON.  So if I understand correctly you are saying that performance-wise a jQuery grid should be better than an ASP .NET grid?

Comment: I think yes, by experience. In fact, It depends of the "complexity" of your ASP.NET component. You'll have maybe many treatments in server side and viewstate dealing. It's partially hidden by Ajax support. On ASP.NET MVC, the complexity is hidden by JSON calls.
It's just my experience, so maybe it's not true !

Answer (score 2):

It's not a mature project but it's sure worth a look, so check out Telerik Kendo UI and grid widget, it's based on jQuery.

http://demos.kendoui.com/grid/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is related to this post:

[jQuery Grid Binding in ASP .NET MVC is so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169643/jquery-grid-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-is-so-slow)

Basically the rendering and databinding of the igGrid (Infragistics jQuery grid) has very small footprint and impact on performance. Moreover, if you enable row virtualization (column virtualization is also supported), it shoudln't matter if you have 100 records or 100 000 in terms of rendering speed.

If you still experience issues which are related to rendering, you can also have a look at the following whitepaper:

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/igGrid_Performance_Guide.html

Let me know if this helps. And thanks for the feedback.
Angel